# Erro na instalação do pacote xlsx

Tags: r

Preciso gravar arquivos que estejam no formato xlsx, uma opção de pacote que faz isso é o xlsx, mas quando fui instalar ele apareceu o seguinte erro:

```
require(xlsx)
Carregando pacotes exigidos: xlsx
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad falhou em loadNamespace() para 'rJava', detalhes:
  chamada: fun(libname, pkgname)
  erro: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Warning message:
package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

Como faço para arrrumar isso e conseguir instalar o pacote?

Comment: Tente: `install.packages('rJava')` e `install.packages('xlsx')`

Comment: Ola, muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas nao deu certo, esta aparecendo o mesmo erro

Comment: Por favor, copie o sua sessionInfo(). Pode ser incompatibilidade entre a arquitetura do seu Java e do R (um em 32 bit e outro em 64 bit). Minha recomendação é sair do `xlsx` que usa Java e ir para os pacotes `readxl`, para ler, e `writexl`, para escrever.

Comment: Tenta `install.packages("xlsx", dependencies = TRUE)`

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Tive um tempo atrás o mesmo problema que o seu. A minha solução foi mudar de pacote. Atualmente utilizo o pacote

Instalando

```
install.packages("readxl")
```

Carregando o pacote

```
library(readxl)
```

Ele é muito bom; até para abrir o arquivo da sheet que você quer ele consegue

Segue o link do site da documentação:

https://readxl.tidyverse.org/

Answer (score -2):

Também estava com este erro e consegui solucioná-lo instalando/atualizando o JAVA.
Tem que ser o 64-bit
https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Answer (score -2):

Para corrigir esse problema acesse:

1º Tools

2º Global Options

3º R version -> Change -> selecione "O use your machines's default version of R (32-bt)"

Agora vamos direcionar o "Java JRE"

#Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301")
library(rJava)

Obs.: Caso não tenha Java JRE instalado na sua máquina link abaixo para download

https://www.oracle.com/br/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html

Agora instalar o packages "xlsx"

#install.packages("xlsx")

library(xlsx)

Agora só carregar os arquivos -> xlsx

Se lhe ajudou só comentar.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.